# Add watermark image to video via AVMutableComposition, exported video size much larger than original

Tags: swift, video, avfoundation, watermark, avmutablecomposition

I have a 30 seconds video clip (1280*720, size around 3MB, *.MP4) and a logo image(4KB, JPG). I've managed to add the watermark and exported video using the following code, but the problem is:

1. The exported video is around 20MB, could we make the video size less than 5MB while remain 1280*720 resolution or similar quality?
2. The export process takes around 20 seconds, is it possible to make it faster?
3. If I set `AVAssetExportSession` to `AVAssetExportPresetMediumQuality`, it indeed becomes faster but the video quality isn't good enough

My goal is to make the whole process(add watermark and export) under 5-8 seconds while remain the pretty much same video quality and size? Is it possible? Thanks in advance.

```
func merge(videoPath: URL, withForegroundImage foregroundImage: UIImage, completion: @escaping (URL?) -> Void) {
        let videoUrlAsset = AVURLAsset(url: videoPath, options: nil)

        let mutableComposition = AVMutableComposition()
        let videoAssetTrack = videoUrlAsset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaType.video).first!
        let videoCompositionTrack = mutableComposition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: AVMediaType.video, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid)
        videoCompositionTrack?.preferredTransform = videoAssetTrack.preferredTransform
        try! videoCompositionTrack?.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRange(start:CMTime.zero, duration:videoAssetTrack.timeRange.duration), of: videoAssetTrack, at: CMTime.zero)

        addAudioTrack(composition: mutableComposition, videoUrl: videoPath)

        let videoSize: CGSize = (videoCompositionTrack?.naturalSize)!
        let frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: videoSize.width, height: videoSize.height)
        let imageLayer = CALayer()
        imageLayer.contents = foregroundImage.cgImage
        imageLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 40, y: 20, width:50, height:50)

        let videoLayer = CALayer()
        videoLayer.frame = frame
        let animationLayer = CALayer()
        animationLayer.frame = frame
        animationLayer.addSublayer(videoLayer)
        animationLayer.addSublayer(imageLayer)

        let videoComposition = AVMutableVideoComposition(propertiesOf: (videoCompositionTrack?.asset!)!)

        videoComposition.animationTool = AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool(postProcessingAsVideoLayer: videoLayer, in: animationLayer)

        let documentDirectory = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.cachesDirectory, FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask, true).first!
        let documentDirectoryUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: documentDirectory)
        let destinationFilePath = documentDirectoryUrl.appendingPathComponent("result.mp4")

        do {
            if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: destinationFilePath.path) {
                try FileManager.default.removeItem(at: destinationFilePath)
                print("removed")
            }
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }

        let exportSession = AVAssetExportSession(asset: mutableComposition, presetName: AVAssetExportPreset1280x720)!

        exportSession.videoComposition = videoComposition
        exportSession.outputURL = destinationFilePath
        exportSession.outputFileType = .mp4

        exportSession.exportAsynchronously { [weak exportSession] in
            if let strongExportSession = exportSession {
                print("exported")
                completion(strongExportSession.outputURL!)
            }
        }
    }

    private func addAudioTrack(composition: AVMutableComposition, videoUrl: URL) {
        let videoUrlAsset = AVURLAsset(url: videoUrl, options: nil)
        let audioTracks = videoUrlAsset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaType.audio)

        let compositionAudioTrack:AVMutableCompositionTrack = composition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: AVMediaType.audio, preferredTrackID: CMPersistentTrackID())!

        for audioTrack in audioTracks {
            try! compositionAudioTrack.insertTimeRange(audioTrack.timeRange, of: audioTrack, at: CMTime.zero)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have a look at this question and answer and the notes around frame rate and size: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33662431/334402

Comment: @Mick Thanks. I'll go take a look